# No provider for Service in x.routes.ts

Tags: angular

I am doing token based authentication for my angular2 app and i have done it using latest r.c.3 router

this is my code in site.routes.ts file

```
import {Authentication}  from './authenticaton.service';
import { RouterConfig,CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { SiteComponent} from './site.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';
export const SITE_ROUTES: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SiteComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent,
        canActivate: [Authentication]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

There is no error during compile time but when i try to access profile route it gives me this error in console.

**No provider for Authentication!**

I have tried giving provider of Authentication but decorators are not supported in x.routes.ts files

here is my authentication.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate,Router,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService }  from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class Authentication implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    // Not using but worth knowing about
    next:  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you provided the `Authentication` in the `ProfileComponent`. Or do you use the `Authentication` in your `AuthGuard`?

Comment: i made the edits, please check again.

Comment: Can you add the code from `Authentication`?

Comment: done, it's authentication.service.ts

Comment: Show ur bootstrap function and sitecomponent if provided ans doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add const with router providers in site.routes.ts:

```
export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(SITE_ROUTES),
  Authentication
];
```

And than add APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS to your bootstrap function.

```
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'site.routes.ts';


    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        ...
        APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: there was a problem with the way i had used isLoggedIn bit, working fine now.